# Lightning Web Component Scope

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a event listener that is firing to handle the creation for new leads.

Within the handler, I am calling a method to determine the source of the lead and identify the record type. However, one value is getting set but the other is not. See code snippet

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getCallInfo from '@salesforce/apex/myclass.getCallInfo';
import getCustomSettings from '@salesforce/apex/myClass.getCustomSettings';
import getConfirmSource from '@salesforce/apex/myClass.getConfirmSource'; 
import { 
    createRecord,
    generateRecordInputForCreate,
    getRecordCreateDefaults
} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import LEAD_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Lead';
import { NavigationMixin } from  'lightning/navigation';

export default class CallStateTracker extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {



    /* Declaring getters and setters. */



    @wire(getCustomSettings) //Wires automatically invoke the APEX method within the paranetheses. 
    customSetting; 

    @wire(getRecordCreateDefaults, { objectApiName : LEAD_OBJECT})
    leadCreateDefaults;


    @api
    get lastCaller() {
        return this._lastCaller;
    }

    set lastCaller(value) {
        this.setAttribute('lastCaller', value);
        this._lastCaller = value;
        this.searchCaller();
    }

    @api
    get lastCallerName() {
        return this._lastCallerName;
    }

    set lastCallerName(value) {
        this.setAttribute('lastCallerName', value);
        this._lastCallerName = value;
    }

    @api
    get lastCallerSource() {
        return this._lastCallerSource;
    }

    set lastCallerSource(value) {
        this.setAttribute('lastCallerSource', value);
        this._lastCallerSource = value;
    }

    _lastCallerSource;

    _lastCaller;

    _lastCallerName;


    @track persons;

    @track shouldDisable = false;



/* Methods and handlers */ 



    handleNewLead() {
        this.shouldDisable = true;
        let badge;  // sets the business badge 
        let myRecordTypeId; 
        console.log('_lastCallerSource ==> ' + this._lastCallerSource); 
        getConfirmSource({lastCallSource: this._lastCallerSource})
            .then(response => {
                if(response == 'Lead2'){
                    // this.badge = 'Value2'
                    this.myRecordTypeId = this.customSetting.data.Lead_Id_2__c;
                    console.log('RECORDTYPE --> ' + this.myRecordTypeId ); 


                } 
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error; 
                console.log('ERROR SETTING RECORD TYPE ==> ' + this.error); 
            }) 

        if(!this.leadCreateDefaults.data) {
            return false;
        }

        let name = this._lastCallerName;

        if(name === undefined || name.trim() === '') {
            name = 'Not Provided';
        }

        if(name.match(',')) {
            name = name.split(',');
        } else {
            name = name.split(' ');
        }

        const leadObjectInfo = this.leadCreateDefaults.data.objectInfos[
            LEAD_OBJECT.objectApiName
        ];

        const leadDefaults = this.leadCreateDefaults.data.record;
        const leadInput = generateRecordInputForCreate(
            leadDefaults,
            leadObjectInfo
        );

        leadInput.fields.Company = name.join(' ');
        leadInput.fields.FirstName = name[0].trim();
        leadInput.fields.LastName = name.length > 1 ? name[1].trim() : name[0].trim();
        leadInput.fields.Phone = this.lastCaller;
        leadInput.fields.LeadSource = this._lastCallerSource;
        leadInput.fields.RecordTypeId = this.myRecordTypeId; 

        let _parent = this;

        let personName = (leadInput.fields.FirstName + ' ' + leadInput.fields.LastName).trim();
        if(personName == "") {
            personName = "No Name";
        }
        console.log('RecordId passed ==> ' + leadInput.fields.RecordTypeId);
        createRecord(leadInput)
            .then(lead => {
                this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                    type: 'standard__recordPage',
                    attributes: {
                        actionName: 'view',
                        recordId: lead.id
                    }
                });

                _parent.persons = [
                    {
                        recordId: lead.id,
                        name: personName,
                        recordType: badge, 
                        icon: 'standard:lead'
                    }
                ];
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: There is not enough code in the above. if you're doing this in a `.forEach()`, for example, then 'this' context won't be captured automatically, you have to pass it in.

Comment: I can post more but the issue is primarily with the fact that "let myRecordTypeId" is not getting assigned the value once the getConfirmSource is fired. Salesforce doesn't even recognize the value. It's almost as if, my method is firing after CreateRecord.

Comment: Ahm, so `is not getting assigned the value prior to getConfirmSource()` -> this is in line with the code you posted? you didn't assign the value, it is assigned in the promise callback.

Comment: Sorry, just edited the post. I think it's because I'm calling two apex classes. Will post my @wires.

Comment: `It's almost as if, my method is firing after CreateRecord` this is very possible, especially if you're using `@wire`. You do need to include more JS as i mentioned in my first comment as atm it is not clear what is going on

Comment: Just posted more. I'll post the whole snippet ... one sec.

Comment: So this is just two `@wire` properties. these can be easily enhanced switching to method syntax with a 'dataReady' flag. But to actually tell you where to place it, we need to see how your code flows from `handleNewLead() `to the second block `const leadDefaults = this.leadCreateDefaults.data.record;`

Comment: just posted fresh code snippet. Not familiar with the dataReady flag...is this a decorator?

Comment: Ok my dude, this is not even an LWC or Salesforce specific problem. Read up on promises. You set the value in the promise call back on line 86 then you attempt to use it outside the promise on line 127. Of course it is not working, because line 127 is reached BEFORE 86.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.